# Java japanese characters string size in bytes

Tags: java, encoding

I'm trying to calculate the length of the String of japanese characters
 '漢字仮名交じり文' :

```
    String testStr = "漢字仮名交じり文";
    try {
        System.out.println("Length : " + testStr.getBytes("UTF-16").length);
    }
        catch(Exception ex) {
        ..... 
    }
```

There are 8 characters in the string and this excerpt prints : 18. Why is it 18?

Answer (score 7):

It is 18 since your have 8 characters each encoded as UTF-16 which means 2 bytes each. Consequently this is 8*2=16 plus the 2 byte BOM which got inserted at the beginning of the byte array!

This is your byte sequence (feff is the so called BOM or Byte Order Mark which allows to detect if the byte sequence is using little endiion or big endian byte order):

```
fe ff 6f 22 5b 57 4e ee 54 0d 4e a4 30 58 30 8a 65 87
```

This is how I printed the byte sequence (it is crude code only meant for testing this out of course):

```
final String text = "漢字仮名交じり文";
byte[] bytes = text.getBytes("UTF-16");
for (int i=0; i<bytes.length; ++i) {
    System.out.printf("%02x ", bytes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the *byte* count, which is not the *character* count.  depending on the encoding (you used UTF-16), a character can be from 1 to 4 bytes.

Comment: Of course I am counting the bytes. I have to clarify my question. I knew that japanese characters are 2 bytes long, apparently they could be up to 4 bytes long. I thought that the size must be 16. Apparently some there is no strict rule on the character size. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong! You described UTF-8 which encodes a unicode character into a 1 to 4 bytes long encoding. UTF-16 is either encoded as 2 bytes or in some character ranges into 4 bytes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16 or http://www.unicode.org/ for reference.

Comment: @user2101649 there is a very strict rule in how UTF-8 or UTF-16 or UTF-32 do work, including the BOM and how decoders should behave

Comment: @clearwater; thanks for the correction.  I was referring to encoding in general, and true UTF-16 can be either 2 or 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to find the character count in a given string, an easy way to do (not optimal) it is

```
   String testStr = "漢字仮名交じり文";
   System.out.println(testStr.toCharArray().length);
```

Prints 8

Comment: Just use testStr.length() :-)  that will do it, all the time, always correct.

Comment: It is encoding indepdendent since it simply returns the number of unicode characters in the string. Encoding is just used when reading or storing strings in some form outside the JVM.

Comment: @arynaq Actually what I wanted to do was to recognize the last symbol of my string. Eventually I need to search for it in any given string and remove it.